# Why is the custom to put the wedding ring on the index finger under the chuppah?

Tags: minhag, wedding, kiddushin-eirusin

Obviously the kiddushin would be valid if one put the ring on another finger, but:

- why specifically does the groom put the wedding ring on the bride's index finger under the chuppah?
- where did this practice originate from?

Sources welcome!

**NOTE**: the "[Minhag to wear wedding ring on the right hand](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48376/minhag-to-wear-wedding-ring-on-the-right-hand/48379#48379)" question provided [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48379/18474) which begins to touch on it, but the link to the article/ source quoted is broken

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150227104205/http://www.netplaces.com/jewish-weddings/the-ceremony/ayrusin-the-ring-ceremony.htm

Answer (score 4):

See sefer Chupat Hatanim dine birkat Irusin.

> ויקדש בימין סידיה וגם בימין הכלה, ובאצבע הסמוך לגודל שנקרא אצבע ישים הטבעת כי דרך הנשים לשים הטבעת באצבע (המ''מ מינץ). והכנסת הגדולה כתב שהמנהג עכשיו לשים הטבעת באצבע קטנה, מכל מקום אנו נותנים טבעת קידושין באצבע מפני שנאמר המנהג כן מזמן שהיו נוהגים לשים הטבעת באצבע. וחיד''א כתב וכן הוא מנהיגנו להשים טבעת הקידושין באצבע הסמוך לגודל הנקרא אצבע וכן הוא מנהג כל ספרד אשר שמענו שמכם, עד כאן. וכבר ידוע הרמז האמור על מזמור השמים מספרים שנזכר בו  והוא כחתן יוצא מחופתו, דכשתתחיל למנות התיבות באצבעות ידיך מפסוק תורת ה' תמימה וגו', בכל פעם יבוא תיבת יתברך שמו באצבע, ולבסוף, הנחמדים מזהב, תיבת "מזהב" נופלת על האצבע לרמוז דהוי מקודש דכבר קדשוהו שמים ליתן בו טבעת הקידושין, והוא המצאה.‏

The minhag, from Maharam mints and minhag sefarad is  that the kala takes the ring with the second finger of her right hand. Kneset Hagedola echoes a minhag at his time to take with the fifth finger. He attributes the variations to habits of women to take generally rings with one or another finger. As it's linked to fashion. Afterwards the Chidda is quoted,  he agrees that the minhag is to use the second finger. There is a remez in a mizmor, but the author doesn't consider it as a valuable argument.